# Phantom arrow in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

The code

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color
set output "C:\\Users\\cole1\\Desktop\\gnuplot_w3.eps"
set multiplot
set isosamples 140
unset key
set title "r"
set xrange [-6:6]
set yrange [-6:6]
set zrange [-4:4]
set zlabel "Energy" 
set label "(arbitrary units)" at 0.001,40
set hidden3d nooffset
set style arrow 1 lw 2 head filled size 0.1,20,70
unset key
set ztics 1
set view 69,120 #Done implicitly by mousing.
set arrow 1 nohead from 0,0,0 to 0,0,4.0 as 1 back
# set arrow 2 nohead from 0,0,0 to 0,4.5,-1 as 1 back
# set arrow 3 nohead from 0,0,0 to 4.5,0,0 as 1 back
splot (x**2+y**2+1)**(0.5),-(x**2+y**2+1)**(0.5)
# set arrow 4 nohead from 0,0,2.5 to 0,0,4.0 as 1 front
unset xtics 
unset ytics 
unset ztics  
set parametric
set samples 1000
plot 0.06*sin(25*t)-1,0.06*cos(25*t)-0.5 lw 1 lc rgb "green"
plot 0.012*sin(25*t)-1.045,0.02*cos(25*t)+2.465 lw 3 lc rgb "green"
unset xtics 
unset ytics 
unset multiplot
```

produces only one arrow in the final result. However, uncommenting the first line in that code    which is commented out (set arrow 2 nohead from 0,0,0 to 0,4.5,-1 as 1 back), causes TWO new arrows to appear. Where does this second arrow come from, and how can this phenomenon be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `set arrow` applies to all following `[s]plot` commands. The `arrow 1` does not appear again, because it has the same x and y values, so the problem appears only for the second arrow. Put an `unset arrow` after the `splot` to avoid the problem.

And you should also `unset title`, or use `set multiplot title 'r'` instead. Beware also, that the margins of the `plot` do not coincide with those of the first `splot`.